# SQL statement advice?

Tags: sql

I've got an interesting query and I'm wondering if anyone can assist.

I have a table with Order Id's, and 4 other tables with various details about the orders.

Table 1

```
OrderID
1234
```

Table 2

```
OrderID   Priceperunit
1234      0.23
```

Table 3

```
OrderID  Retail   PriceLocatorCode
1234     0.78     34567
```

Table 4

```
OrderID   DistributorCode   SupplierCode
1234      7654              3567
```

Id love to be able to create an SQL statement using Table 1 at its base, that brings through Priceperunit, Retail Price, Locator Code, Distributor Code and Supplier Code, along with all the fields that are already in Table 1.

Eg) (I've missed out the remaining field here as I've run out of space!)

```
OrderID   PricePerUnit   RetailPrice   LocatorCode
1234      0.78           0.23          34567
```

Order ID is the key field on all of the tables.

I've been trying with Joins and the UNION and UNION ALL commands and have got stuck.

Comment: you need 3 joins (probably `LEFT JOIN`s)

Comment: Thanks @Lamak my SQL isn't the strongest. Could you elaborate please?

Answer (score 2):

Check with following code

```
SELECT t1.OrderId,t2.PricePerUnit,t3.RetailPrice,t3.LocatorCode,t4.DistributorCode,t4.SupplierCode
 FROM TABLE1 t1
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 t2 ON t1.OrderId = t2.OrderId
LEFT JOIN TABLE3 t3 ON t1.OrderId = t3.OrderId
LEFT JOIN TABLE4 t4 ON t1.OrderId = t4.OrderId
WHERE t1.OrderId=1234
```

If you want to add other fields from Table 1 then just add column in select statment.